# Is it possible to insert a row in a table in ORACLE DBMS which has been inherited?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just had a quick question, The below three tables have inheritance using UNDER,

```
CREATE TYPE MenuType AS OBJECT(
 MenuCode VARCHAR2(5),
 Description VARCHAR2(20)) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE TABLE Menu of MenuType (
MenuCode PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TYPE VegetarianType UNDER MenuType (
 ProteinLevel VARCHAR2(20));
/

CREATE TABLE Vegetarian of VegetarianType;

CREATE TYPE LowFatType UNDER MenuType (
 KCal VARCHAR2(20));
/

CREATE TABLE LowFat of LowFatType;
```

Is it possible to insert a row in the Menu table which represents a Vegetarian diet? or would it be just inserting a row in the Vegetarian Table?

Thanks in advance,

Ahsan

Answer (score 1):

You do not need separate tables for the sub-types and can just insert them into the `MENU` table and then use the `TREAT` function to convert to the sub-type as needed:

```sql
CREATE TYPE MenuType AS OBJECT(
 MenuCode VARCHAR2(5),
 Description VARCHAR2(20)
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE TYPE VegetarianType UNDER MenuType (
 ProteinLevel VARCHAR2(20)
);
/

CREATE TYPE LowFatType UNDER MenuType (
 KCal VARCHAR2(20)
);
/

CREATE TABLE Menu of MenuType (
  MenuCode PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then you can `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO Menu
VALUES ( VegetarianType( 'VEGE1', 'Vegetarian Meal 1', 'Lots of Protein' ) );

INSERT INTO Menu VALUES ( LowFatType( 'LFAT1', 'Low Fat Meal 1', '500kCal' ) );
```

Then you can use `TREAT` to get the values from the sub-type's fields:

```sql
SELECT m.*,
       TREAT( VALUE(m) AS VegetarianType ).ProteinLevel AS ProteinLevel,
       TREAT( VALUE(m) AS LowFatType ).KCal AS KCal
FROM   Menu m;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> MENUCODE | DESCRIPTION       | PROTEINLEVEL    | KCAL   
> :------- | :---------------- | :-------------- | :------
> VEGE1    | Vegetarian Meal 1 | Lots of Protein | null   
> LFAT1    | Low Fat Meal 1    | null            | 500kCal
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6347280760861d3bbafd439aa638d81e)*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was doing it a similar way but I didn't know about the Treat function